# need to develop a JAVA program to compare the database

Tags: java

i need to develop a program in JAVA where i am suppose to compare one database with the other and generate the output for the unique data..please help me out with the procedure that is to be followed ...

Answer (score 1):

Well.. first you compare the list of tables, then the list of columns in each table and finally individual rows.

- get tables: [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)
- get columns: [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- get rows/cells: [`ResultSet.getObject()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28java.lang.String%29)

All in all, there are only 3 levels where a discrepancy might come up and if it does, simply record the difference into an `ArrayList` or the equivalent and move on.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to compare two databases:

1. Same schemas: every table has the same name, same columns; every column has same type; same constraints; same relationships.
2. If two databases have the same schemas, do they contain identical data?

Which one do you mean?

Your question is far too broad, but if you're using Java to access a relational database you're sure to need JDBC.  How well do you know it?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html